# aws api gateway header validation against matching pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-api-gateway, openapi, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating an AWS API Gateway using terraform and openAPI specification with swagger. I need to add a request validator for validating the headers against a matching pattern [a-zA-z0-9]{10}. I was able to set up basic validator that checks if the header is empty or not but not able to validate with the pattern.

```
 "x-amazon-apigateway-request-validators" : {
    "full" : {
      "validateRequestBody" : true,
      "validateRequestParameters" : true,
       "validateRequestHeaders" : true
    },
    "body-only" : {
      "validateRequestBody" : true,
      "validateRequestParameters" : false
    }
  },
  "x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator" : "full",
  "paths": {
    "/validation": {
    "get": {
            "parameters": [
              {
                "in": "header",
                "name": "x-request-id",
                "required": true,
                "type": "string",
                "pattern" : "^[a-z0-9]{10}$"
              },
              {
                "in": "query",
                "name": "name",
                "required": true,
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z]{5}$"
              }
            ]
       }
}
```

Please suggest if there is any way to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a workaround for your requirement. You may use a "request based" [**Lambda authorizer**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html) and implement the validation logic within the Lambda function. If you need to validate just one header you may use 'token based' Lambda authorizer as well and specify a token validation regex.

Once the Lambda function determine whether the incoming headers are valid, it can grant access to the API.

You can check how to [**Configure a Lambda Authorizer Using the API Gateway Console**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/configure-api-gateway-lambda-authorization-with-console.html).

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
"type": "string",
"pattern" : "^[a-z0-9]{10}$"
```

it should read

```
"schema": {
  "type": "string",
  "pattern" : "^[a-z0-9]{10}$"
}
```

see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70240057/aws-api-gateway-schema-validation-with-custom-formats/72344864#72344864)